# Flutter to display Draft JS content

Tags: flutter, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

The two pub package I found on draft JS for Flutter seem to be no longer maintained.

Is there anyway to display Draft JS content that is coming from the database onto Flutter?

How are my other fellow developers who use Draft JS rendering their content in Flutter? or some other mobile app like news app (e.g. Channel News Asia or IGN) render their content detail?

Answer (score 0):

End up using webview instead. I made a custom webpage with it own url for the detail that will be shown on the webview.

Not sure if it is a good way of doing it though.